# Conditionaly parsing JSON file

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "RouteTables": [
        {
            "Associations": [], 
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-ce3c7daa", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-87cf4de3", 
            "PropagatingVgws": [], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "ItMgmtUsEastPublic", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "GatewayId": "local", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.168.254.0/23", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable"
                }, 
                {
                    "GatewayId": "igw-961518f3", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-27e68942", 
                    "Main": true, 
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-92ff64f7"
                }
            ], 
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-92ff64f7", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-b8fc75dd", 
            "PropagatingVgws": [], 
            "Tags": [], 
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "GatewayId": "local", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/16", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable"
                }, 
                {
                    "GatewayId": "igw-27cd1542", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute"
                }
            ]
        }
```

I Want to parse this JSON in a way when there's values in `Tags[]` write it, otherwise print `No Tag` line for Tag

i have this code:

```
with open('1.json') as file:
 data = json.load(file)

 for element in data['RouteTables']:
  s=element['RouteTableId'] + ',' + element['VpcId']
  if 'Tags' in element:
   for route in element['Tags']:
    d = route['Value']
   else:
    d = 'No Tag'
  for route in element['Routes']:
     r=route['DestinationCidrBlock']
     print s+','+d+','+r
```

and no matter if there is Tag or not, it prints `No Tag`

desired output:

```
rtb-ce3c7daa,vpc-87cf4de3,ItMgmtUsEastPublic,192.168.254.0/23
rtb-ce3c7daa,vpc-87cf4de3,ItMgmtUsEastPublic,0.0.0.0/0
rtb-92ff64f7,vpc-b8fc75dd,No Tag,172.31.0.0/16
rtb-92ff64f7,vpc-b8fc75dd,No Tag,0.0.0.0/0
```

Current results:

```
rtb-ce3c7daa,vpc-87cf4de3,No Tag,192.168.254.0/23
rtb-ce3c7daa,vpc-87cf4de3,No Tag,0.0.0.0/0
rtb-92ff64f7,vpc-b8fc75dd,No Tag,172.31.0.0/16
rtb-92ff64f7,vpc-b8fc75dd,No Tag,0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: You could use four spaces for indented blocks. One-character indentation is difficult to follow. Is your `else` supposed to be linked to your `for` or is that a mistake?

Comment: `if  needs to check if `Tag`s exists, if not,assign d='No Tag' and procced further with executions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed your code a bit. Basically you need to reinitialize d for every iteration.

```
for element in data['RouteTables']:
    s=element['RouteTableId'] + ',' + element['VpcId']
    d = 'No Tag'
    if 'Tags' in element:
        for route in element['Tags']:
            d = route['Value']
    for route in element['Routes']:
        r=route['DestinationCidrBlock']
        print s+','+d+','+r
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line in your code:

```
if 'Tags' in element:
```

By:

```
if element['Tags']:
```

Comment: in this way only, No Tag lines are written

Comment: @Milister  In your code every element has 'Tags' key but problem is with your condition that returning false all the time. So, once you try above code and I think its work.

Comment: @Milister Welcome :-)

Answer (score -3):

I think you have the indentation of the 'else' wrong. This way you have a for...else, instead of an if...else.

Comment: if there is any indentation error the code does not executed.It display indentation error while running.